# Minimal cross-browser web-push services/libraries for saas product

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal, web-push

I am looking for services/libraries to send notifications on browsers, for a SaaS product(would be installed on many websites). I have following needs

- API access to send push notification from server individually. (dont need segmentation, channels, analytics... all those things)
- Simple setup in minimal time, not different code for different browsers.
- Support for as many browsers as possible. (I saw some services support safari too)
- Not very costly, given that I dont need complex features, just 1-1 send via API.

I have tried few of services, no libraries. and my comments are

- FCM, pushcrew: doesn't support safari.
- onesignal: looks like their privacy policy says they will collect data of my visitors and use it make their profile and use it serve them better ads.(it is like selling data)
- roost: little bit expansive just for notifications(offers many other features)
- izooto: limits on number of websites + very costly just for notifications.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it. "

Comment: I didn't knew it, But I was looking for recommendations based on my requirements. May some other forum is good for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Pushpad (I am the founder).

- It offers a REST API and libraries for Ruby, PHP, Node.js, Python and Java
- It has features explicitly designed for web apps. For example you can easily [target specific users](https://pushpad.xyz/docs/identifying_users) in a safe way
- It offers a unified interface to all browsers and web push services
- It supports all the browsers that currently support the Push API and also supports APNs for Safari
- We don't collect and resell data - it's a key point for Pushpad
- We support multiple websites and subdomains
- Pricing is based on the number of notifications sent

Comment: Looks good enough! Any plans for IE/Edge support? I read that they are also supporting service worker now! And if in future I want to move to some other service/custom solution, will I get all tokens needed for that, so that I don't have to ask for permissions from each of them visitors again?

Comment: @hridayesh We are already working to support Edge [as announced](https://blog.pushpad.xyz/2017/12/microsoft-edge-now-supports-web-push-notifications/) some days ago on our blog. Currently we are waiting an answer from Microsoft, since it looks like Edge [has a bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15194521/) (status: *confirmed*) that prevents us from sending the notifications. In any case no further action will be required on your side to support Edge: Pushpad will start working out of the box as soon as the bug is fixed.

Comment: @hridayesh For the subscriptions: absolutely yes, you can export them. You can export both the endpoints and the VAPID key pair. It's all you need. Just make sure that you use Pushpad Pro, so that subscriptions are associated to your own domain.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!